# How can I edit my Entity Framework model after adding new tables to the database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing ASP.Net MVC application and I am using Entity Framework Model.
My question is, after a few days, I have added extra tables to the database and I am wondering what should I do? Do I have to add new Entity framework model(s) or update the existing one? If I need to update the existing one, would you please let me know how?

Thanks

Comment: You have to update it. Open your edmx file in your model, right click and select Update Model from Database. Then, select your new tables and click finish. And save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data model, it is not necessary to add new one.
In your data model graphic:

right click/ update data model / add tables ( select your new tables) / finish

with this you can add new tables and update the other tables.